# Textbox not declared...can not do .text but only .value

Tags: vb.net, webforms

Goodday,

Very confused. Dazzled. Everything.. :-) I have made a page...this is the page:

---

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Contact.aspx.vb" Inherits="Contact" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>blabla</title>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="bl" />
<meta name="keywords" content="blabla" />
<meta name="author" content="blabla" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //
    }); //


</script>       
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <div style='text-align:center'><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://www.theie6countdown.com/images/upgrade.jpg"border="0"alt=""/></a></div>  
    <![endif]-->    

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>      
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="not-front">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

<div id="main">
 blabla
<div id="inner">

<div class="top2_wrapper">
<div class="bg1"><img src="images/bg1.jpg" alt="" class="img" /></div>
<div class="top2_inner">
<div class="container">
<div class="top2 clearfix">

<h1>contact us</h1>

<div class="breadcrumbs1"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a><span></span><a href="Default.aspx">Pages</a><span></span>Contacts</div>

</div>  
</div>  
</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span9">

<h2><span>blabla</span></h2>

<figure class="google_map">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3894.331481453587!2d99.95368306057432!3d12.5603807486186!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xbaa61d3b0e1607b0!2sBaan%20Khun%20Por%20Hotel!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sth!4v1574141019645!5m2!1sen!2sth" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</figure>

<h3>blabla</h3>

<p>
blabla<br />
blabla<br />
blabla<br />
blabla
</p>

</div>
<div class="span3">

<h2><span>blabla</span></h2>

<ul class="ul1">
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
</ul>



</div>  
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="span12">

<h2 class="center"><span><%=bt.gettext("contactform", Session("lang"))%></span></h2>

<div id="note"></div>
<div id="fields">
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputName">NAme</label>
                    <div class="controls">                    
                      <input runat="server" class="span4" type="text" id="inputName" name="name" value="Your full name:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your full name:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Your full name:' ) this.value=''">
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>  
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">                    
                      <input runat="server" class="span4" type="text" id="inputEmail" name="email" value="Your email:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your email:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Your email:' ) this.value=''">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
                    <div class="controls">                    
                      <input runat="server" class="span4" type="text" id="inputPhone" name="phone" value="Phone number:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Phone number:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Phone number:' ) this.value=''">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                    <div class="controls">                                        
                      <textarea runat="server" class="span12" id="inputMessage" name="content" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Message:'" 
                        onFocus="if(this.value =='Message:' ) this.value=''">Message:</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="control-group capthca">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputCapthca">Checkbox</label>
                    <div class="controls">                    
                      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf8bMQUAAAAAHswc18w7_FunyOQKa9Z0Tkj79YI"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Send" runat="server" Text="Send" />
    </form>
</div>  

</div>  
</div>

</div>  
</div>

<div class="bot1_wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="bot1 clearfix">
<div class="row">
<%=cn.GetCopyRight()%>
<%=cn.Getfootermidden()%>
<%=cn.Getfooterright()%>
<%=cn.GetSocial%>
</div>
</div>  
</div>  
</div>

</div>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>`
```

---

On the code behind page, I want to send an email after clicking the [send] button. This is the code behind.

```
    `enter code here
    Protected Sub Send_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Send.Click
        If Len(Request("g-recaptcha-response")) > 0 Then
            'Mail versturen
            Dim objMail As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
            Dim objSMTP As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
            Dim objCred As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential()

            Try
                objMail.Subject = "Mail"

                'objMail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("sssa@soemhing.com")
                objMail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("blabbla@bla.com")

                objSMTP.Host = "secret"
                objCred.UserName = "secret"
                objCred.Password = "secret"
                objSMTP.Credentials = objCred
                objMail.IsBodyHtml = True

                objMail.Body = "Name: " & inputName.Value & "<br>" &
                "Email: " & inputEmail.Value & "<br>" &
                "Phone: " & inputPhone.Value & "<br><br><br>" &
                "Text: " & inputMessage.Value & "<br>"

                objMail.To.Add("blabla@gmail.com")
                objMail.CC.Add(inputEmail.Value) 'Sender CC
                objSMTP.Send(objMail)

                Response.Write("<br/><br/>")
                Response.Write("<center>")
                Response.Write("<h1>Mail sent. You recieve a CC of the message sent. <a href=""Default.aspx"">Home</a></h1>")
                Response.Write("</center>")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write("<br/><br/>")
                Response.Write("<center>")
                Response.Write("<h1>Error sending mail. Please, contact us in another way.<h1><br><br>Error: " & ex.Message)
                Response.Write("<h1>Email blabla8@gmail.com directly<h1>")


                Response.Write("<br><br><a href=""Default.aspx"">Home</a>")
                Response.Write("</center>")

            End Try
            'objMail = Nothing
        Else
            Response.Write("<h1>You did not check the 'I am not a robot' checkbox.</h1>")
        End If


        Response.End()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

I really dont understand why it says in code behind (when I build)...
inputName, inputEmail, inputPhone and inputMessage are "BC30451 'inputName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level" and I cant not do a textbox.text but I have to do a textbox.value.

Any Ideas? I appreciate already for reading this.

mo3s

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how this markup:

```
<input type="text" id="greeting" value="hello" runat="server" />
```

Is mapped in code:

```
greeting.Value 'hello is the value, greeting is of type System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText
```

---

If you want textbox behaviour, use a textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="greeting" Text="Hello" runat="server"><asp:/TextBox>
```

Then your code is:

```
greeting.Text 'hello
```

Comment: Thank you very much Caius Jard.     I have changed it to e.g.   <asp:TextBox ID="inputName" runat="server" Text="Your full name:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your full name:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Your full name:' ) this.value=''"></asp:TextBox> and yes...I can do a .text ..... still at build it says "BC30451 'inputEmail' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: `"inputEmail" != "inputName"`?